# The limit of product of two functions, where one tends to infinity and the other to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

If we know that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, then what will be $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x))$? How do you prove the result?

By using examples I can see that the limit can be $\infty$, $-\infty$, $0$ and any other real number depending what your $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are but I am not sure how to construct a proof-like argument here.

Comment: There is nothing to prove. If you can construct your examples, you will have shown that there is no general statement about this case (granted that you can prove that your examples show what you want them to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an example where $f(x)\to\infty$, $g(x)\to0$ and $f(x)g(x)$ tends to a given real number $c$ as $x\to a$, just take
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\quad\hbox{and}\quad g(x)=c(x-a)^2\ .$$